# Eziriz .NET Reactor Obfuscator performance

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, security, obfuscation

I am planning to use .net reactor v4.5 to secure my application. I have a .NET 2.0 application written in vb.net optimized for performance. If I choose the "Application Strongest" preset in the software, will it slow down the performance of my application due to the overhead process of decrypting / guarding the application every time it runs?

Thanks,
Albert

Answer (score 1):

Usually yes, and specifically depending on which options you choose.

I had tried both **Eziriz .NET Reactor** and **Intellilock** for some months and I do notice a very slight lag when the application first start, but during the runtime of the application I do not see performance difference between a protected and a unprotected application.

> "guarding the application every time it runs"

This is not the definitive cause, but more so due to injection of extra code and functions such as loops of obfuscated line as it compiles. But there are also options that may even help with performance (e.g. compression). All in all it depends on your choice of protection options.